# camel stub end point for testing

Tags: apache-camel

How does the stub end point works in apache camel ?

Let's say i want to simulate sending message to MQ now instead of actual queue name for in my test properties i will be having end point as stub:abc

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-stub/src/main/docs/stub-component.adoc

Now how do i assert from this stub how many messages were sent to the stub?

Seems like i am missing some part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stub is just like a dummy queue. If you want to assert messages etc then take a look at the mock endpoint instead. Where you can setup expectations, eg how many messages to receive, what data they should contain etc.

I suggest to read/study more about testing with Camel in the documentation, 3rd party blogs, examples, and in books.

Comment: Yeah, right i already spent more time in trying out different code to get what i want rather than reading.